# OpenGL 2d get x,y coordinates android

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates

If I have a point at `-3f, 3f, 0.0f` in OpenGL
and I do `gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f)`
then I draw the object.  Where will that point be drawn at in x,y screen coordinates? 
(screen width = 800 , height = 480).

Comment: Clipping will kill this point entirely (assuming identity transformation matrices). It has a constant w coordinate of **1.0**, which makes everything outside the range [**-w**,**w**]. The point **-3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0** would work. That'd be drawn 3/4 of the way to the top of your screen, and 3/4 of the way to the left.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't apply any additional transformations, like a view or projection transformation, it will pass through the different coordinate systems like this:

- original coordinates: (-3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f)
- after translation (clip coordinates): (-3.0f, 3.0f, -6.0f)
- no change from perspective division (normalized device coordinates): (-3.0f, 3.0f, -6.0f)
- after viewport transformation (window coordinates): (-800.0, 960.0)

So the answer is: Far off the screen! Clipping would come into play after the second step. If this is just a point, it would get eliminated by clipping right then. If it's part of a primitive that has points inside the view frustum, the primitive would be clipped accordingly.